# Can't deploy liferay theme

Tags: node.js, gradle, npm, liferay, npm-install

I'm working on a liferay project and I can't deploy the theme.

The npmInstall gradle task is causing the issue.

Here is the error I have :

> Execution failed for task ':themes:montheme:npmInstall'

I don't have any issue with running npm install from the terminal in my theme repository. It's really the gradle task.

I have tried to clone the project in both my computer environment (node : v16.20.1, npm : 8.19.4) and my Virtual Machine (node : v12.14.1, npm : 6.13.4)

Both are facing the same issue. My colleagues who cloned the same project don't face this issue, it's been a few days I have been stuck on it now.